# Nodejs NPM module not found while building webpack.dll

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, node-modules, webpack-dev-server

I am using nodejs 12.16.0 and NPM 6.13.4
I get module not found error as below when i do **npm run build:dll**.

```
ERROR in ./~/spdx-expression-parse/scan.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'spdx-exceptions' in '/home/proj1/fronter/node_modules/spdx-expression-parse'
@ ./~/spdx-expression-parse/scan.js 6:17-43
@ ./~/spdx-expression-parse/index.js
```

When i try to list modules as below cli command :

```
npm list -g | grep spdx
    │ ├─┬ spdx-correct@3.0.0
│ │ ├── spdx-expression-parse@3.0.0 deduped
│ │ └── spdx-license-ids@3.0.3
│ └─┬ spdx-expression-parse@3.0.0
│   ├── spdx-exceptions@2.1.0
│   └── spdx-license-ids@3.0.3 deduped
```

So you can see that spdx-exceptions module is there. But scan.js is throwing error that this module not found.

When i look at node_modules directory, i can also see both modules there.

[image]

I also installed modules manually again, it was successfull. But still giving module note found error although module is there.

The code throwing the error is scan.js from spdx-expression-parse module. It gives not found for require()

```
var licenses = []
  .concat(require('spdx-license-ids'))
  .concat(require('spdx-license-ids/deprecated'))
var exceptions = require('spdx-exceptions')
```

There are more module not found errors, i just shared one of them to be focused on solution.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to your problem? I'm experiencing something similar with yeoman-environment and its dependencies on sdpx-extensions.